# Name Entity Recognition is not recognizing multiple words correctly in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

So I am attempting to do a Name Entity Recognition task using NLTK in Python. However, this doesn't do the job that I want it to do.

I have an input file such as following

```
magic johnson is the owner of l.a. lakers.
ceo kevin johnson citing issues related to covid 19 as the reason for the deal’s termination.
susan somersille johnson went to school to be an engineer, yet somehow managed to carve out a nearly 30 year career in marketing.
```

and my current code is.

```
import nltk
import re

sentence = ""

with open("test.txt", "r") as inFile:
    sentence = inFile.read()

for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence):
    for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
        if hasattr(chunk, 'label'):
            print(chunk.label(), ' '.join(c[0] for c in chunk))
```

However this falsely recognized the names and organizations and outputs only

```
ORGANIZATION l.a.
```

Why doesn't this work? How can I make this work?

My expected output is that something like

```
magic johnson
l.a. lakers
Kevin johnson
etc.
```

Comment: How do you define "work"?  What did you expect it to do here?  If you print the individual chunks before the `hasattr` call, you'll see that it has correctly identified all the nouns, verbs, and other parts of the sentence.  NLTK is an infinitely complicated tool.  I think you have more reading to do.

Comment: @TimRoberts what I mean is that I need the output to capture names and others such as "magic johnson" and "l.a. lakers" etc. But it doesn't do that here.

Comment: @TimRoberts as you have mentioned. If you look at the output that way it gives you ```('magic', 'JJ')``` and ```('johnson', 'NN')```.

Comment: You told it to divide the text into words.  If you want it to group words into larger names, you will have to use a different kind of tokenization.  Go scan through the NLTK book.  It has submodules for doing many, many different kinds of semantic analyses.